# Reading a txt file in Python

Tags: python, numpy, text-files

I'm trying to read a text file named `testfile.txt`.
I use the NumPy function `genfromtext`, however I get an `Index error: Too many indices`.

The textfile consists of 6 columns of numbers:

```
% Notes: 1A
% Mach Number: 
% Barometric Pressure: 1036 bar
% Load using MATLAB command: data = load('filename')
% Columns: mm, p/pt, C4, C5, C4raw, C5raw
     44.800000          0.781381        804.605260       1029.721933         -0.015945         -0.001723
     56.800000          0.681254        699.772376       1027.182448         -0.022291         -0.001977
     59.800000          0.627379        643.578986       1025.821491         -0.025692         -0.002113
     62.800000          0.572096        586.082966       1024.447808         -0.029170         -0.002250
     74.800000          0.440294        449.643875       1021.234840         -0.037422         -0.002571
     79.800000          0.384134        391.777963       1019.900507         -0.040921         -0.002705
     84.800000          0.336203        342.518031       1018.784082         -0.043898         -0.002816
     96.800000          0.270190        274.847768       1017.238791         -0.047987         -0.002971
```

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
table = np.genfromtxt("testfile.txt",dtype = "float",delimiter = ",",comments = "%")

mm = table[:,0]
ppt = table[:,1]
C4 = table[:,2]
C5 = table[:,3]
C4raw = table[:,4]
C5raw = table[:,5]

print ppt
```

Comment: More info is needed: your input file (or part of it) and the full error

Comment: On what line of your code does that error occur?

Comment: the error occurs at the line mm=table[:,0], the textfile consists of six columns of numbers. I have added an image of the textfile

Comment: Then `table` isn't 2-dimensional, so indexing it with two indices can't work. `print table` to see what it contains or `print table.shape` to see the [sizes of its dimensions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html).

Comment: Not comma delimited, is it? Appears to be tab-delimited to me.

Comment: It is comma delimited, I printed out the table, I just get a huge list with al the elements from my textfile. Even the lines which start with a "%", which shoud be deleted because I included comments = "%".

Comment: @aeengineer if it is comma delimited, then where did the commas go?

Comment: Haha, I am wondering that as well, I tried using your lines, but it gives me the same result

Answer (score 1):

Since the default for `genfromtxt` is to use (possibly multiple) whitespace as delimiter, you can have what you need with just:

```
table = numpy.genfromtxt('testfile.txt', comments="%")

# etc.
```

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html):

> By default, genfromtxt assumes `delimiter=None`, meaning that the line is split along white spaces (including tabs) and that consecutive white spaces are considered as a single white space.

Answer (score 1):

Your file is not comma delimited. Try this instead:

`table = np.genfromtxt("test1.txt", dtype="float", comments="%")`

With the example you provided, this returns the correct values for me.

Comment: `comments` is indeed a better parameter than `skip_header` in this case :o)

Comment: I managed to get it to work:
table = np.genfromtxt("testfile.txt", dtype="float", delimiter=" ", comments="%")

mm = table[:,0]
ppt = table[:,1]
C4 = table[:,2]
C5 = table[:,3]
C4raw = table[:,4]
C5raw = table[:,5]
print mm

Comment: @aeengineer do you see those `\t`? Your file is not comma delimited, it is tab-delimited. Use the second line in my answer above, that should work.

Comment: You can simply omit the `delimiter` parameter. From the docs:
 _By default, genfromtxt assumes delimiter=None, meaning that the line is split along white spaces (including tabs) and that consecutive white spaces are considered as a single white space._
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html

Comment: Okay, I was a bit too enthusiastic. The first column works out fine,
but for the other, I get arrays like this: [nan nan ... nan nan]

Comment: @aeengineer see my update!

Answer (score 0):

Allright, after some trial and error I now solved the problem. 
Thanks for helping me out, omitting the delimiter was indeed the final solution as suggested by heltonbiker.
This is my code:

```
#Read the textfile "testfile.txt" and place all columns in a separate array
table = np.genfromtxt("testfile.txt", comments="%")

mm = table[:,0]
ppt = table[:,1]
C4 = table[:,2]
C5 = table[:,3]
C4raw = table[:,4]
C5raw = table[:,5]
```